# Python: How to save a JSON file without brackets?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to generate a JSON file, however it's generating with brackets which is not intended. How can I overcome this?

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10],
                   "B": [20],
                   "C": [30]})

df.to_json('file.json', orient='records')
```

**file.json**

```
[{"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}]
```

**expected output**:

```
 {"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}
```

Answer (score 5):

use the option `lines=True`. You won't get square bracket in file and get the desirable output.

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `orient` on `columns` it is quite close to what you want, but includes the index:

```py
df.to_json(orient="columns")
# '{"A":{"0":10},"B":{"0":20},"C":{"0":30}}'
```

which gives you `{column -> {index -> value}}`

Here are all the outputs for your DataFrame:

```
  split    {"columns":["A","B","C"],"index":[0],"data":[[10,20,30]]}
records    [{"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}]
  index    {"0":{"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}}
columns    {"A":{"0":10},"B":{"0":20},"C":{"0":30}}
 values    [[10,20,30]]
  table    {"schema":{"fields":[{"name":"index","type":"integer"},{"name":"A","type":"integer"},{"name":"B","type":"integer"},{"name":"C","type":"integer"}],"primaryKey":["index"],"pandas_version":"0.20.0"},"data":[{"index":0,"A":10,"B":20,"C":30}]}
```

---

Using [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) orienting as `list`:

```py
repr(df.to_dict(orient="list"))
# "{'A': [10], 'B': [20], 'C': [30]}"
```

Here are the rest of the `repr`s for `to_dict`:

```
   dict    {'A': {0: 10}, 'B': {0: 20}, 'C': {0: 30}}
   list    {'A': [10], 'B': [20], 'C': [30]}
 series    {'A': 0    10
Name: A, dtype: int64, 'B': 0    20
Name: B, dtype: int64, 'C': 0    30
Name: C, dtype: int64}
  split    {'index': [0], 'columns': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'data': [[10, 20, 30]]}
records    [{'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30}]
  index    {0: {'A': 10, 'B': 20, 'C': 30}}
```

Comment: Is possible to remove the Index?

Comment: The closest that I could get was using `to_dict` (see the updated answer).